# Complexity of QBF with Restrictions on Models

Tags: time-complexity, sat

Do you know the complexity of the following decision problem?

Given a quantified boolean formula (QBF) $\phi$ with $2n$ free variables with $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is there a satisfying assignment s.t. exactly $n$ free variables are `true` and $n$ free variables are `false`.

I am also interested in the easier case, where we consider propositional logic instead of QBF. What would the complexity be then?

Comment: It is straight forward how to turn an arbitrary formula $\varphi$ with $n$ variables to a formula $\psi$ with $2n$ variables s.t. $\varphi$ is satisfiable iff there is a satisfying assignment with hamming weight $n$ for $\psi$. The reverse direction is also not difficult.

Comment: Sorry, the first direction by intuition seems possible and I think I know how. The second direction does not seem obvious at all. Can you give pointers?